# How to get Radius tags parsing FBML correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, fbml, radiant

I am using the [Radius Tag System](http://radius.rubyforge.org/) (from the RadiantCMS) for a content engine in my current applciation. Everything has worked really well, but now I am experiencing issues when using FBML inside my content.

When I supply a tags like the following to my template:

```
<fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" size="square"></fb:profile-pic>
```

Radiant gets confused, incorrectly parsing the close tag and outputting:

```
<fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" size="square"> /fb:profile-pic>
```

... which in turn breaks the FBML parsing engine.

I am not using the fb prefix for Radius, so there is no clash, and indeed, I can get many of the tags to work by using the self-closing format:

```
<fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" size="square"/>
```

Self-closing is fine in many cases, but being able to provide content for a tag means that there is content visible while the Facebook connect engine loads.

Comment: Do I get my rep back now :p ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick analysis showed, that Radius has a problem with closing tags that contain namespaces. This is in no way a Facebook only problem.

Comment: Hmmm ... I suspected as much.